# How to redirect static files with htaccess by remove of one url part

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, static, mod-alias

I have such a query:

```
/upsell/someextrapath/images/image1.png
```

This path does not exist.
I want to create a rule with htacess, which removes %someextrapath% from the url, so url will be working.

PS: this %someextrapath% can vary from one page to another. This is the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch ^/upsell/.+/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /upsell/$1/$2
```

Comment: hollly mother of god!!! it works!!! thank you, a man who understand this really magic language of htaccess!!!